# Routing subdomains in Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, subdomain, routes

I have 2 subdomains for my domain: "www" and "hosting". I made 2 WAR applications: one for the "www" site, and another for the "hosting" site.
Is there any way I can configure Tomcat 7 to route subdomains to web applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reverse Proxy](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html) set up would enable finer control over how the HTTP requests are handled and directed. You would configure the proxy for each of the subdomains to point to the proper applications.

I use [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html) as a reverse proxy in front of my Tomcat webservers.